# Assigning query output to variable in postgres stored proc

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

I am trying to assign a variable the result of a query in a postgres stored procedure.
Here is what I am trying to run:

```
CREATE OR Replace PROCEDURE schema.MyProcedure() 
AS $$

DECLARE 
    RowCount int = 100;
    
BEGIN
    
    select cnt into RowCount 
    from (
        Select count(*) as cnt
        From schema.MyTable
        ) ;
    
    RAISE NOTICE 'RowCount: %', RowCount;
    
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

**schema.MyTable** is just some arbitrary table name but the script is not displaying anything, not even the random value I assigned RowCount to (100).

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You either either need to use an `inout` parameter to return the value, or use a function instead of a procedure to `return`  a value.

Comment: I dont need the RowCount returned, I was just using Raise Notice to check if the true table's row count was being assigned to the RowCount variable.

Comment: Works for me, though  I did have to add an alias for the subquery: `...From schema.MyTable) as ct`, to CREATE the procedure.  `call myprocedure (); NOTICE:  RowCount: 68`. Also I would avoid using mixed case identifiers. Best guess is you are not calling the procedure you think you are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an alias for the subquery, for example : `as sub`

```
CREATE OR Replace PROCEDURE schema.MyProcedure() 
AS $$

DECLARE 
    RowCount int = 100;
    
BEGIN
    
    select cnt into RowCount 
    from (
        Select count(*) as cnt
        From schema.MyTable
        ) as sub ;
    
    RAISE NOTICE 'RowCount: %', RowCount;
    
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Though it could be simplified to: `Select count(*) into RowCount from ...` and eliminate the sub query.

Answer (score 0):

You can also assign any variable with a query result in parenthesis.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE schema.my_procedure()
AS
$$
DECLARE
    row_count BIGINT;
BEGIN

    row_count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM schema.my_table);

    RAISE NOTICE 'RowCount: %', row_count;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

You should use BIGINT instead of INT.

And it's far better to write your code and table definition with snake_case style as possible.